# Why the first result does not appear in the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a log file like this

> time1-step1
>   time2-step2
>   time4-step1
>   time6-step3
>   time8-step2
>   time9-step3

I wrote this python script to convert log file to xlsx:

```
import os  
import xlsxwriter

# title
row1 = ["step","1","2","3"]
row2 = ["time"]

def addSheet():
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')    
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write_row('A1', row1)
    worksheet.write_row('A2', row2)

    with open('test.log', 'r',encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f1:
        row = 1
        for line in f1.readlines():
            new_line = line.strip()
            time = str(new_line[0:5])
            col = 1
            if "step1" in new_line:
                print ("step1" , time)
                worksheet.write(row, col, time)
            if "step2" in new_line:
                print ("step2" , time)
                worksheet.write(row, col+1, time)
            if "step3" in new_line:
                worksheet.write(row, col+2, time)
                row += 1
    workbook.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    addSheet()
```

actual result is like

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+
|step|  1  |  2  |  3  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+
|time|time4|time2|time6|
|    |     |time8|time9|
+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Why does the first result "time1" not appear in the file?

Comment: You copied and pasted the log file or typed here?, there is a spelling mistake for step in step3

Comment: It is a test file.    
But I  still have a problem .    
If I delete the time3-step3 , then  run script, the result still doesnot contain time1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some logical errors. The only time you increase your row is when you enter a value for `step3`

In your log files -

> time1-step1 
>   time2-step2 
>   time4-step1 
>   time6-step3 
>   ...

You have 2 `step1` entries before `step3`. This means that this line of code -

```
if "step1" in new_line:
                print ("step1" , time)
                worksheet.write(row, col, time)
```

overwrites your entry for `time1` with the entry for `time4`

You could fix this by using separate counters for each `stepX` set